# Olympus Camera Kit: Need to acquire captured image in the original size after shooting

Tags: ios, olympus-camerakit

I am trying to make capture program with Olympus Camera Kit (ver. 1.1.0) for iOS. I'd like to get captured image as soon as possible in the original size after shooting.

I know the original image can be transferred in playback mode, but it may take time to change the run mode from recording mode to playback mode. How can I get the image in original size while the camera runs in recording mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible means to acquire captured image in the original size, but none of these work in recording mode. Only for playback mode. Only if the camera property `RECVIEW` is `ON`, XGA-size image is transferred in recording mode.

1. Change destination to store captured image

You can directly transfer captured image to your mobile device when the camera property `DESTINATION_FILE` is set to `DESTINATION_FILE_WIFI`.
Note that the captured image is NOT SAVED to the microSD card in the camera.
onReceiveCapturedImage method is called back the camera finishes shooting.

Continuous shooting is invalid and movie is stored in microSD card.

2. Check update of file list

Check the update of file list before and after shooting with `downloadContentList`, then detect the difference.
The original image can be downloaded with `downloadImage(IMAGE_RESIZE_NONE)` method.

You can check if the camera is in memory access with `isMediaBusy` property.
Stop live view transfer calling `stopLiveView` to efficiently download the image. Call `startLiveView` to resume live view transfer.